# How to monitor or profile a slow .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Can anyone tell me how to go about determining the culprit on a slow running process.  I have a page that queries an Active Directory and a SharePoint Server to get information.  It makes several calls to each Server (retrieving customer information).  I am wondering if there are any tools available to profile a web application looking for this type of information, slow running methods, etc.

Thanks for any tips given...

Comment: Can you run it from Visual Studio in Debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend YourKit over some of the others. An I believe there is a free trial

http://www.yourkit.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try setting Trace="true" for Page like this

```
 <%@ Page ... Trace="true" ... %>
```

and it will generate trace info at the bottom of the page like this

[image]

And here's an [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx) related to that.

Answer (score 2):

Without any tool, start by surrounding "interesting" methods calls with [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). 
Log the results somewhere ( I suppose you already have a log enabled ) and you probably will discover the performance pitfall. If this fails, follow the Oded reply ;)

Answer (score 2):

Attach a profiler to the process.

There are several commercial ones - [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/), [memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) and others.

These will give you statistics regarding where time is spent, what functions were called most etc...

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) SO thread with recommendations.

---

Update:

This will supplant the information that `trace="true"` will give (as answered by @Bala) and give you more detail (for example, if you are calling *both* AD and SharePoint in PageLoad, you are no closer to an answer).